# TVOS - Keyboard color changes on backgrounding app when using UISearchController

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, tvos, uisearchcontroller, apple-tv

I am using Swift 5, testing on a 4K Apple TV.

I am using the UISearchController without subclassing. I am trying to display a white search bar and keyboard on a dark background. So I set:

`self.searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .dark`

(I've tried this in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear)

This creates a search bar and keyboard that looks like:
[image: Image on first launch]

Then if I hit the menu button to leave my app and go back to the Apple TV home page and resume the app it changes the keyboard bar black:
[image: Image after Backgrounding App]

Any ideas what is going on here?

(Note: When running this on the Simulator in Xcode the search bar stays white after backgrounding, I don't know why but it only seems to happen on actual Apple TVs)

Comment: Hello! Have same issue here. You solved it?

Comment: I did get it working but it was a while ago, and I'm not 100% sure which line solved it but I think it is one of these:

`self.searchController.searchBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
self.searchController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
`

Comment: @ksiit where did you put any of these lines of code for it to work for you. Put them in viewDidLoad but doesn't seem to work for me